# fwrite a pid_t not working

Tags: c, fwrite

I have the follwoing code:

```
...
printf("Started %d", pid);
FILE * fh;
fh = fopen("run/source.pid", "wb");
fwrite(&pid, sizeof(int), 1, fh);
fclose(fh);
```

However the written pid file writes jargon, and not the integer, I though pid_t was just an `int`, I even tied doing `sizeof(pid_t)` for the second argument I get similar issues.

Any ideas? Thanks for the help in advance.

Thanks

Comment: POSIX says: `blksize_t`, `pid_t`, and `ssize_t` shall be signed integer types. have you tried with `fprintf(fh, "%d", pid);` instead of `fwrite()` just to see what happens.

Comment: That worked, but I still cant understand why it wont work with fwrite

Comment: I posted an answer for you to see, hope my answer is clear enough and typo free for that matter. XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well I do not understand quite well the question (too little context), but the issue may be is that you are seeing the file in a text editor, terminal, etc..

fwrite() writes raw data, for example, suppose you have a pid number, lets say 12, and you write that number using fwrite like this:

```
fwrite(&pid, sizeof(int), 1, file);
```

fwrite() will write a 32 bit integer into the file `file`, that is, depending in your processor type, a byte sequence like this: `00 00 00 12`

However

fprintf() will write a byte sequence of : `49 50` (ASCII characters platform independent) visible among all terminals or text editors.

Hope this helps.